# редирект с поддомена на домен с сохранением пути и параметров

Tags: .htaccess

Необходимо настроить редирект `poddomen.site.ru/some-paht/` на `site.ru/some-paht/?region=poddomen`.

Но чтоб если в пути есть параметр, 
например - `poddomen.site.ru/some-paht/?parameters=param1`,
перенаправляло на `site.ru/some-paht/?parameters=param1&region=poddomen`.

То есть путь и параметры после доменного имени заранее неизвестны, надо просто весь путь и параметры сохранять, только к ним дописывать как доп. параметр имя поддомена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант, в котором даже имя поддомена неизвестно.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).site.ru$
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1?region=%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Если же надо перенаправлять только один поддомен, а остальные не трогать, то правила несколько изменятся:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^poddomen.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1?region=poddomen [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Отмечу, что за сохранение параметров GET-запроса отвечает опция `QSA`.

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает.